# CSS3 file not formatting html page --

Tags: html, css

I'm putting a simple website (HTML 5 and CSS3) for a friend yet I can't understand why the CSS file is not loading and formatting the page.

Here is the synopsis:

1. I've coded the page using "liveweave" and there are no call out errors and the page is looking as it should.
2. The .css file exists on the server (in the same dir as the index.html file - I'm referencing it as you would in the header section of my code:

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <title>Styleyes Eyewear</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://styles.herobo.com/styleyes.css">
 </head>
  <body>
    <!-- header area -->  
    <div class="header_div">
      <a href="http://styleyes.herobo.com"><img src="http://styleyes.herobo.com/img/logo_small.png" alt="Styleyes Eyewear"></a>

      <!-- navigation area -->  
      <nav class="nav">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="http://styleyes.herobo.com/products">PRODUCTS</a></li>
          <li><a href="http://styleyes.herobo.com/culture">OUR CULTURE</a></li>
          <li><a href="http://styleyes.herobo.com/stores">STORES</a></li>
          <li><a href="http://styleyes.herobo.com/follow">FOLLOW US</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <!-- content area --> 
    <div>
      <img width="100%" src="http://styleyes.herobo.com/img/homepage_girl.jpg">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

3. Inside "liveweave" you can combine the files (html and css) into the one file. I've done this and uploaded it as a reference and the site, again looks fine - here is a link to that:

liveweave dev page:
http://liveweave.com/XI5QT7

combined code into "source.html" and loaded onto the webserver

```
http://styleyes.herobo.com/source.html
```

So Im not sure why when I have my "index.html" seperate to my ".css" its not picking it up? If the .css file exists and I'm calling it from the index.html file as described above, It should in theory format the page.

but this is what I'm getting...

http://styleyes.herobo.com/

Any ideas as to why this is happening? Is it something in my code? I've tried on different browsers and different computers - giving same results.

Thanks!

Comment: spelling of domain name is different in head section..

Comment: stylesheet link gives a 404

Comment: there is a typo mistake here `<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://styles.herobo.com/styleyes.css">` should be `<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://styleyes.herobo.com/styleyes.css">`

Comment: @thebjorn is correct.  Change the domain to `styleyes` and it works as expected.  Also, if the stylesheet is in the same directory, you don't need the full path.  Just use `styleyes.css`

Comment: ARGH! how embarrassing... Thank you guys for helping me out with this...

Comment: yeah... the domain name is not an easy one to type.. it plays tricks on you. thanks again guys!!! much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If your `.html` and `.css` are inside of the same directory, you should use relative URI instead of absolute ones (like this):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styleyes.css">
```

Also: In your live version, the CSS is actually simply not accessible (Error 404). Is the filename spelled correctly?